# uploading media file to s3 contains auto-compression?

Tags: c#, video, amazon-s3, synchronization, compression

I uploaded mpeg4 file from my local to s3. the file size is 10M on local while the file size is just under 1M. compression itself doesn't matter, but the uploaded file on s3 cause a/v async problem. I want to solve the a/v async issue.
My code is as follows.

```
TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AmazonAccessKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AmazonSecretKey"], RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
// making a TransferUtilityUploadRequest instance
TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();        

if (subDirectoryInBucket == "" || subDirectoryInBucket == null)
{
    request.Key = fileNameInS3; //file name up in S3
}
else
{   // subdirectory and bucket name
    request.Key = subDirectoryInBucket + @"/" + fileNameInS3; //file name up in S3                                
}
request.BucketName = bucketName; //no subdirectory just bucket name
request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
request.FilePath = localFilePath; //local file name
utility.Upload(request); //commensing the transfer
```

If there is anyone who experience this problem, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it has changed recently, which it does regularly..., a standard transfer to S3 should not be compressing your video. I would take a look at the wider client code to see if the compression is happening there, or at the logs to see if the transfer is not completing properly for some reason.